# Is it possible to get client's ip address by configuration in rabbitmq's message?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I want to get rabbitmq's client ip address in message. 
1. One way is for application to gain it.
2. Anther way is modify rabbitmq's source code to gain it.

But is it possible to get it by configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get client ip in message (body or headers) unless you put it there manually.