# How to get the IP of who is sending a message?

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

I'm trying to create a game, so imagine if I have 2 clients: Player A and Player B.

Both already sent a message to the server to identify themselves. So both are logged in.

Now Player A wants to attack Player B. How can I keep the IP or something of the players so the server is able to send a message to Player B letting him know that he is being attacked?

I am using rabbitmq.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get client's ip address by configuration in rabbitmq's message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494920/is-it-possible-to-get-clients-ip-address-by-configuration-in-rabbitmqs-message)

Answer (score 1):

The way that I've handled this in the past is for the clients (players in your case) to have their own queue. Or, if you want to notify all players you can set up a topic exchange.

He is a setup that I have right now.

Direct Exchange: App.Server (Clients Publish, Server Consumes)
Direct Exchange: App.Client.UniqueIDForClient1 (Server Publishes, Only Client 1 Consumes)
Direct Exchange: App.Client.UniqueIDForClient2 (Server Publishes, Only Client 2 Consumes)
Topic Exchange: App (Server Publishes, All Clients Subscribe to App.Client)

If you are using c#, this is how you setup and publish to the topic exchange:

```
ConnectionFactory mqFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
mqFactory.HostName = "localhost";
IConnection mqConnection = mqFactory.CreateConnection();
IModel mqChannel = mqConnection.CreateModel();

mqChannel.ExchangeDeclare("App", "topic", true);

response = "This Message Will Go To All Topic Subscribers";
mqChannel.BasicPublish("App", "App.Client", null, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));
```

I don't currently have the consumer/subscriber code handy as my client is currently a web app using PHP/AJAX.

Here is a link to the offical RabbitMQ tutorial which has the subscriber side examples: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-dotnet.html

Comment: hmm...I don't think my question was answered

Comment: @Seva I'm not sure what you are asking for then... You want your server to be able to direct a message to a specific player and a direct exchange back should accomplish that. I would use a unique id over an IP address as more than one player could be coming from the same IP. If you're looking for some way to keep track of who is who on the server side, then keep a list of which players belong to which queues. You can either have a new player send some sort of registration message via RabbitMQ or use the 'reply_to' attribute when the player publishes a message.